# Using yup and formik, is there a means of displaying an info message that isn't an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

Currently using Yup with Formik and instead of producing an error message on the screen where the user needs to action, is there a means of displaying an info type message instead, that doesn't stop processing of the form?

At the moment I am using `<ErrorMessage></ErrorMessage>`

Perhaps there might be another means of achieving this but based on some value entered, I purely want to display a message underneath the textfield input that is information only.